# how create Date header like WhatsApp in flutter chat

Tags: flutter

I am new in flutter. I am trying to build chat application using Firebase. I want to show group message with date header just like WhatsApp chat.

Comment: What you have tried ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [grouped_list](https://pub.dev/packages/grouped_list) package

```
GroupedListView<dynamic, String>(
elements: _elements,
groupBy: (element) => element['group'],
groupSeparatorBuilder: (String groupByValue) => Text(groupByValue),
itemBuilder: (context, dynamic element) => Text(element['name']),
itemComparator: (item1, item2) => item1['name'].compareTo(item2['name']), // optional
useStickyGroupSeparators: true, // optional
floatingHeader: true, // optional
order: GroupedListOrder.ASC, // optional),
```

you can group by dates and returns massages

Comment: Thank you so much. That's I am looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Also u can use https://pub.dev/packages/sticky_grouped_list package

```
StickyGroupedListView<dynamic, String>(
    elements: _elements,
    groupBy: (dynamic element) => element['group'],
    groupSeparatorBuilder: (dynamic element) => Text(element['group']),
    itemBuilder: (context, dynamic element) => Text(element['name']),
    itemComparator: (element1, element2) => element1['name'].compareTo(element2['name']), // optional
    itemScrollController: GroupedItemScrollController(), // optional
    order: StickyGroupedListOrder.ASC, // optional
  ),
```

Answer (score 1):

In case someone is stuck this is how I solved it:

```
  final Stream<QuerySnapshot> movimientosStream = db
        .collection('users')
        .doc(auth?.uid)
        .collection("movimientos")
        .orderBy("updated_at", descending: true)
        .snapshots();
```

```
body: StreamBuilder<dynamic>(
        stream: movimientosStream,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text('Something went wrong');
          }

          if (snapshot.connectionState ==
              ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Text("Loading");
          }


          return StickyGroupedListView(
    elements: snapshot.data?.docs,
    groupBy: (QueryDocumentSnapshot<Object?>? document) => DateFormat.MMMMd("es").format(DateTime.parse(
        document?.get('updated_at'))),
    groupSeparatorBuilder:(QueryDocumentSnapshot<Object?>? document)  =>
    Text(document?.get("updated_at")),
    itemBuilder: (context, QueryDocumentSnapshot<Object?>? document) =>
    Text(document?.get("amount")),

    );
```