# How to add WhatsApp-like date headers in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to add date header like WhatsApp.

Here are two examples:

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

I've read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65422913/16124033) and referenced [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65423220/16124033) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65959964/16124033) answer, but there is a problem.

I can use both [`grouped_list`](https://pub.dev/packages/grouped_list) and [`sticky_grouped_list`](https://pub.dev/packages/sticky_grouped_list) packages, but there is no `cacheExtent` field so it's useless for me.

My code:

```
ListView.builder(
  cacheExtent: 9999.0,
  controller: controller,
  itemCount: itemCount,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) => ChatBubble(),
),
```

I hope I can do it with some custom code or other package.

Feel free to leave a comment if you need more information.

How to add WhatsApp-like date headers in Flutter? I would appreciate any help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Where are you stuck at? 
Is it the UI part? or something else such as creating a Header after X amount of other widgets?

Comment: @MendelG I've created some widgets (chat bubbles) and I'm stuck on the created date header

Comment: How about using [`ListView.separated`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView/ListView.separated.html)?

Comment: @MendelG can you share more code and details on how to do it

Comment: I didn’t get your issue, you want to show some widget that stick to the top of the message?! @MyCar

Comment: @eamirho3ein I want to do something like WhatsApp where the first message sent today will say "Today" or the date at the top.

Comment: @MyCar do you need use cacheExtent to build more item before loading them?

Comment: when you set `cacheExtent` to something that big it doesn't much difference than set `shrinkWrap` to true, both of build all the item at the same time. @MyCar

Comment: @eamirho3ein yes you are right. Back to the question, how to add date header like WhatsApp?

Comment: @MyCar now you can use `shrinkWrap` instead of `cacheExtent` in those packages that you provided.

Comment: @eamirho3ein is there a `shrinkWrap` field in that package?

Comment: Yes I see that. @MyCar

Answer (score 0):

[image]

i make this for my project, i made it simple for you, you can customize, this is the basic idea:

```
class MyList<T> extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<T> listModel;
  final double? cacheExtent;
  final Widget Function(BuildContext, int index) listBuilder;
  final List<Widget? Function(T listValue)> separatorsBuilder;
  const MyList({Key? key,required this.listModel, required this.listBuilder, required this.separatorsBuilder, this.cacheExtent}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final childreen = _buildChildreen(context);
    return ListView.builder(
        cacheExtent: cacheExtent,
        itemCount: childreen.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index){
      return childreen[index];
    });
  }

  List<Widget> _buildChildreen(BuildContext context){
    List<T> remain = List.from(listModel);
    List<Widget> result = [];
    int separatorCount = 0;
      for (var separator in separatorsBuilder){
        bool separatorUsed = false;
        while(remain.isNotEmpty){
          if(separator(remain.first) != null){
            if(!separatorUsed){
              result.add(separator(remain.first)!);
              separatorUsed = true;
              separatorCount++;
            }
            final index = result.length - separatorCount;
            result.add(listBuilder(context, index));
            remain.removeAt(0);
          }
          else {
            break;
          }
        }
      }

    return result;
  }
}
```

The list i use in example :

```
final now = DateTime.now();

    List<MyModel> myModel = [
      MyModel(message: 'hello, yesterday', dateTime: now.subtract(const Duration(days: 1))),
      MyModel(message: 'hello, this from yesterday', dateTime: now.subtract(const Duration(days: 1))),
      MyModel(message: 'hello, this me yesterday', dateTime: now.subtract(const Duration(days: 1))),
      MyModel(message: 'yes, this is now', dateTime: now),
      MyModel(message: 'sure this message is today', dateTime: now),
      MyModel(message: 'this message sent today', dateTime: now),
    ];
```

use it like this in widget tree:

```
MyList<MyModel>(
                  listModel: myModel,
                  listBuilder: (context, index) {

                    return ListTile(
                      title: Text(myModel[index].message),
                    );
                  },
                  separatorsBuilder: [
                    (data) {
                      if (data.dateTime.isYesterday()) {
                        return Container(color: Colors.blue,child: const Text("Yesterday"));
                      }
                      return null;
                    },
                    (data) {

                      if (data.dateTime.isToday()) {
                        return Container(color: Colors.blue,child: const Text("Today"));
                      }
                      return null;
                    }
                  ])
```

mymodel :

```
class MyModel {
  String message;
  DateTime dateTime;

  MyModel({required this.message, required this.dateTime});
}
```

some extension will useful in your case :

```
extension DateHelpers on DateTime {
  bool isToday() {
    final now = DateTime.now();
    return now.day == day &&
        now.month == month &&
        now.year == year;
  }

  bool isYesterday() {
    final yesterday = DateTime.now().subtract(const Duration(days: 1));
    return yesterday.day == day &&
        yesterday.month == month &&
        yesterday.year == year;
  }
}
```